# On keydown trigger next tab index (focus next element)

Tags: javascript, angular, dom-events

I am having a bootstrap's dropdown menu (I implemented only styles without Javascript)... hence I need to port to angular2 some js functionality.

One is keyboard accessibility.

So far I have:

```
<div (keydown)="onMenuKeydown($event)" ....>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#"...>option 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"...>option 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"...>option 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

In my controller I have this:

```
onMenuKeydown(event: KeyboardEvent){
    if(event.keyCode === 40){
        /*event.srcElement.nextSibling.*/
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

What I would like is that on arrow down it simulates or triggers the TAB key (so it should focus next element) and on arrow key up to simulate the SHIFT-TAB key (previous tabindex)

I have the `event.srcElement` and have `nextSibling`property but it doesn't have the method focus... so cannot do `event.srcElement.nextSibling.focus();`.

What would be the best solution here?

Comment: how do you switch between tabs? adding/removing a css class?

Comment: not a tab... its a drop down menu... and you can check here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns  ... click on one to open and then navigate with the tab key

Comment: I think that the best way would be to add bootstrap's javascript too in your index.html file. This way you don't have to worry about how to make it work in angular2, since bootstrap will already make it work.

Comment: yeah... sure.. why didn't I thought of that before.... the whole point is to stay clear of jquery and cumbersome js... angular does things just find, just need to figure the way... hope this is not your solution for everything... just include more/everything ...

Comment: I appreciate you taking time trying to help though, don't get me wrong!

Comment: So I think the best way to do it would be to use an angular2 dropdown and add bootstrap style on it. you can even get a bootstrap dropdown made with angular2 on npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-dropdown You can even see the source code on github if you want to copy the behaviour on your component.

Comment: yeah, I am checking the src on different components... cheers

Answer (score 1):

so, for the reference, there is obviously a distinction between *Element* and *HTMLElement*, the later is extended one.

Angular2 has a **ElementRef** you usually use when referencing an HTML element...

so to get a HTMLElement from event.nextSibling you do

```
let next = new ElementRef(event.nextSibling);
```

and the using

```
next.nativeElement.focus();
```

don't forget to include ElementRef in your imports

```
import { Component, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
```

Comment: Could you please explain this @DS_web_developer , as I am also facing the same issue. 

I tried using tabindex but it fails to work in IE. It works only when tabindex=1, but only one time. Then the focus will get disappear once the list is over.